# Hot to convert a Mat object to byte[] data object in "onPreviewFrame" and show it in camera preview

Tags: android, opencv

In my android app, I am trying to take frames in "onPreviewFrame" and convert them to Mat object so i can do on them some image processing, but i don't know how to convert them back to byte[] type and make them be shown on camera preview.

Does any one know how to do that?

Here is my onPreviewFrame function, i am trying to change frame color to grey:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1)
{
    Mat mRgba = new Mat(PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mRgba.put(0, 0, data);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    mRgba.put(0, 0, data);

    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From an older implementation of the OpenCV camera viewer pipeline:

```
private Mat mYuv, mGraySubmat;

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    if(mYuv == null) {
        mYuv = new Mat(height + height / 2, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        mGraySubmat = mYuv.submat(0, height, 0, width);
    }
    mYuv.put(0, 0, data);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mGraySubmat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
}
```

I think you can just call the addCallbackBuffer method in the end and it'd work fine!